# How to disable antivirus software (Windows Defender?) on GitLab's Windows runner?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, malware-detection, false-positive, windows-defender

I am plagued by false-positive malware reports involving `pyinstaller`, which is a known problem (compare [pyinstaller#7967](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/7967)). Now I finally meet these problems on CI, and I am able to reproduce it using a very simple GitLab CI job ([YML](https://gitlab.com/bers/eicar/-/blob/6ce95328d632ffb1f96f0436063972e962119b45/.gitlab-ci.yml) and [Pipeline](https://gitlab.com/bers/eicar/-/jobs/5889318785)), *yet not locally* (`docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809 powershell`). So there may be something GitLab-specific going on.

How do I disable antivirus "protection" on GitLab's Windows runners?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had tried that earlier, but `Set-MpPreference -DisableRealtimeMonitoring $true` works great ([YML](https://gitlab.com/bers/eicar/-/blob/3cbe0b9322ef1e9f1875b231a6271f5bf0df436c/.gitlab-ci.yml) and [Pipeline](https://gitlab.com/bers/eicar/-/jobs/5891608380)).